# Imaginary poles of the Green's function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, singularities, greens-functions, tachyon

I am dealing with a theory with the Green's function that has infinitely many poles on the imaginary axis:

$$G(\omega)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\omega-i\mu_n}$$

where $\mu_n=\cosh(n\beta/2)$, and $\beta$ is some parameter. This means that in time representation

$$G(t)=i\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-\mu_nt}$$

that is, this is a system of infinitely many unstable particles. What physical situation can this correspond to?

Comment: Just for clarity, how are you defining your Green's function? Is it $G(\omega) \equiv \int dt e^{i \omega t} <GS|e^{iHt}Ae^{-iHt} A|GS>$ for some operator $A$ of interest, possibly with extra factors of $i$ or an implicit $\omega \rightarrow \omega + i \epsilon$? Are the operators in the expectation value possibly time-ordered or accompanied by a Heaviside function?

Comment: Yes, as $()≡∫^{}<|^{}^{−}|>$ and time ordering is assumed.

Comment: This does not resemble particles at all. Normally, (quasi)particles are expected to have a width that is (much) smaller than their energy. In your case, the energy (real part of $\omega$ at the pole) is zero. What does your theory look like?

Comment: So, if beta is infinite, your time-domain Green's function (TGF) is always zero, and if beta is zero the TGF diverges linearly as the number of those \mu_n poles. Expanding on what @TomášBrauner said: perhaps you're dealing with Goldstone modes when beta tends to zero? Zero-energy states that form a continuum... If we step away from that limiting case, one has a countable set of infinite zero-energy "excitations", and I currently don't know what to make of that lol.
Thanks for the nice question!

Comment: What is the concrete definition of your Green-function? (The answer depends severely on this.)